# JavaScript querySelector not working when .value is added to it

Tags: javascript

I am creating my program which takes the user input on an Enter key.

I use the userInput with .value in the if statement and it works perfectly. But when I try to use it as a variable, nothing is outputted and nothing is in the console.

I tried to do `querySelector("input['name = "command"]')` to see if it might work but again, nothing outputted and it showed nothing in the console

```
var userInput  = document.querySelector("input[name = 'command']")
var theInput = userInput.value.toLowerCase();
var theConsole = document.querySelector("#console");
theConsole.scrollTop = theConsole.scrollHeight;
var myScroll = document.getElementById("scroll");

    function doAThing(event) {
        var theKeyCode = event.keyCode;
        
        if(theKeyCode === 13) {
        acceptCommand();
        setInterval(scrollUpdate, 1000)
        }
    }
function scrollUpdate() {
    myScroll.scrollTop = myScroll.scrollHeight;
}

function acceptCommand() {
    var p = document.createElement("p");

    if(theInput=== "help") theConsole.append("Help is given!", p);

    //using the keywords
    }
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body id = "scroll">
        <div id="game">
            <div id="console">
            </div>

            </div>
                <div id = "command-box">
                    <div id = "cmd">
                        <input type = "text" name = "command" id = "command" onkeypress = "doAThing(event);">
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Use == insted of === maybe? idk

Comment: The problem is the moment when you get the input value. Apparently you are getting it when the page is loaded, the right thing was to get the value inside `acceptCommand`

Comment: Put `var userInput = document.querySelector("#command")` inside  `acceptCommand`

Comment: @AksJacoves, that isn't actually the problem in this case. You can declare a input's variable and reference it later and get the correct value. Matter of fact, besides the extra end div, I tested this code and it works.

Comment: Since the code you posted is working, where you are trying to use the variable that it isn't working?

Comment: @imvain2

Sorry, I edited it for the parts that didn't work. It's the part in the if statement. I wanted to use theInput instead of userInput.value

Comment: thanks @AksJacoves! it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the div#console element:

```
<div id="console">
```

to this input:

```
<input type="text" id="console">
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to refer to `userInput.value` instead of `theInput`. Because `theInput` is set to the value at the time of setting the variable and it doesn't get updated even though the value of `userInput` changing.